# .htaccess regular expression in Yii when having path url format

Tags: .htaccess, yii, regex

I am trying to set the regular expressions to get some parameters from the url. here is one url example:

```
mydomain.com/files/images/versions/large/uploadedGal/1-36.png
```

and I need to get two parameters out of this `large` and `36` and make a url like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?r=image/default/create&id=36&version=large
```

This is the my regular expression in the htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the requested file or directory does not exist...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# ...and if the source URL points to an image, we redirect to the create image URL.
RewriteRule versions/([^/]+)/[^\-\d]*\-?(\d+)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ index.php?r=image/default/create&id=$2&version=$1 [L,R,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Which doesn't work... I cannot figure out where is the problem, I think it doesn't get the parameters write, and I get the error 404 not found. I am using urlFormat as path BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... your pattern is wrong/bad. Considering your example URL

```
files/images/versions/large/uploadedGal/1-36.png
```

and how it needs to be transformed/rewritten

```
index.php?r=image/default/create&id=36&version=large
```

try this one (definitely works, but you may need to adjust it for different URL types, since you have provided only 1 URL example):

```
versions/([^/]+)/[^\-\d]*(?:\d+\-)?(\d+)\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

or like this (really depends on other possible URLs, but most likely this is what you wanted in first place)

```
versions/([^/]+)/[^\-]*\-?(\d+)\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

---

Your current pattern will match only up to this part `files/images/versions/large/uploadedGal/`.